# Security benchmark for Windows 10 group policies on a non-domain joined computer

Tags: windows, security, group-policy, windows-10

I have used the [CIS security benchmarks](https://www.cisecurity.org/cis-benchmarks/) to design GPOs meeting industry best practices. I am now looking to build a provisioning package to use in configuring machines not bound to AD. Is anyone aware of a similar document listing the minimum settings to be applied?  Alternatively, is there a document which could help in identifying which settings correspond to those in the GPO?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LocalGPO tool to apply the CIS benchmark GPOs to computers that are not joined to a domain.

Comment: Thanks, Sturdy, but I really like the functionality of the .ppkg, and I don't want to overcomplicate it.

Comment: What would you apply that ppkg with?

Comment: Give it to users - double click to install. Can do it during OOBE. https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3339